# Spark (Scala) count duplicate values for each column individually in a dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to get the duplicate count for each column in a dataframe individually.

Input

| id | age | zip |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 22 | 12345 |
| 1 | 32 | 34561 |
| 2 | 32 | 12345 |
| 3 | 44 | 34561 |
| 2 | 45 | 67890 |
| 4 | 66 | 67890 |

The output should contain the count of duplicates for each column

Output:

| id | age | zip |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 3 |

For a single column I am able to do a group by and count
`df.groupBy("id").count.filter("count > 1").count()`

But how do I do it for all the columns and get the output in the desired format?

Also is it possible to do it by spark sql?

Comment: There is a `columns()` function that will return a list of columns. Just iterate through that list and execute the code you wrote for each column name

Comment: Iterating through columns() function I can do but how do I get an output like the one I want? A code sample will be helpful.

Comment: Why do you want this data in a dataframe? It doesn't make sense to have a dataframe with a single row. `count` collects the results in the master node. If you really want a dictionary structure read the results into a `Map`. Otherwise you need to justify why the data needs to be in a `DF` because as is I am not seeing any reasons why

Comment: This is part of a larger one to get various metrics like unique value, null value etc for each column. this is not just one row but part of a bigger output.

Answer (score 0):

navin
You can use the Spark custom accumulator;
This 100% solves this problem!

Comment: A sample code if you could would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
with
cte_id(
  select count("id") as id_c from df group by id
),
cte_age(
  select count("age") as age_c from df group by age
),
cte_zip(
  select count("zip") as zip_c from df group by zip
),
cte_row(
select "id" as col, sum(case when id_c > 1 then 1 else 0 end) as val from cte_id
union
select "age", sum(case when age_c > 1 then 1 else 0 end) from cte_age
union
select "zip", sum(case when zip_c > 1 then 1 else 0 end) from cte_zip
)
SELECT * FROM cte_row 
pivot(
  sum(val) for col in ("id", "age", "zip")
)
```

You can't achieve it directly, above code should serve the purpose. So here cte_id will holds each id occurred how many times, same for cte_age and cte_zip.
cte_row will holds the how many id, age or zip exist which have duplicate.
pivot is used to transform

```
+---+---+
|col|val|
+---+---+
| id|  2|
|age|  1|
|zip|  3|
+---+---+
```

to

```
+---+---+---+
| id|age|zip|
+---+---+---+
|  2|  1|  3|
+---+---+---+
```